# REGEX "Full Name" to "Abbreviated Name"

Tags: c#, regex

We have the need to transform a full name into an abbreviated name, where the combinations of input, vary as follows:

INPUT: [optional title] [forename or initial] [surname]

OUTPUT: [optional title] [initial] [surname]

- Mr Andrew Smith
- Mr A Smith
- A Smith
- Andrew Smith

In all instances, shown above, the output would be **Mr A Smith** (where a title is present) or **A Smith** (where it isn't present) and I figured that this would be best achieved with a RegEx, though I have no idea what the syntax would be to do this correctly.

I have tried a few myself and have only gotten mixed (incorrect) results.

As a note; the names 'could' contain special characters and no one has a middle name; so we could have someone named **Mr James O'Reilly-Bond** in the list, who would result in **Mr J O'Reilly-Bond**

This is being programmed in C#

Comment: This question is ill posed, doesn't have enough examples, doesn't describe conflicting cases, doesn't post code, or specify a language.

Comment: It's being written in C# and the number of example of the names list is pretty much the entire extent of the problem.

Comment: You can't differentiate between names and titles, e.g. Duke

Comment: @MrBones whilst that is correct, we don't have any instances of title/surname, which means that Duke Johnson would always be forename/surname. The RegEx example from Andris (below) has been tested and works exactly to our requirements, for all the possible combination that we know are likely to occur.

Comment: how are we supposed to know that? There's a whole load of implicit assumptions here, which is why I said it's an ill posed question

Comment: I don't mean to pick fault (as I appreciate the time/effort people give to answering questions here), but it's in the first sentence "the combinations of input, vary as follows" and I listed examples of the four possible combinations that we are dealing with and posted a subsequent comment stating that the list was pretty much the extent of what we're dealing with. Take it "as read" rather than making your assumptions; the question is intentionally simple and explicit enough to deal with the require scenario - as Andris has clearly done, by providing an answer that does exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not using regex is certainly an option, I understand not wanting to make the list of possible titles. If it's always 2 names or 3 with the title, you can do fine with `(([A-Z])\S*)(?=\s\S*$)`, as seen https://regex101.com/r/tR7kV2/1 .

The idea is that you select the second to last word, the word is in capture group $1, its capital letter - in capture group $2, you substitute your match with $2.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex. It's much easier to split the string on whitespace and then reason on each component independently (if the first one is Mr/Mrs/Ms, disregard it, otherwise take the first letter).

Comment: I had considered something similar to that (extracting on the first item alone; has quite a few combinations, for the such: Mr, Mrs, Miss, Dr, etc., and looked at splitting to the level that if the split().length = 3 we know that we have a title; if it's 2 then it's just forename/surname. Figured that using RegEx would be faster (processing a lengthy list) and quite a bit tidier, too.

Comment: Regexes are usually *slower* than simple string processing. They aren't magic. ;)

Comment: I disagree with this answer, it's easy to do with a regex and need fewer statement than testing the presence of a group

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with a regex [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP6lP5/1):

```
((?:mr|ms) )?(.).* (.*)
```

with flag `i` for case insensitive and use the Three groups as substitution (you didn't say which language you're using, so I can't give an example)

The first group match an eventual title followed by a space and capture it.
The second group match the first letter of the first word and the third group capture the last word (last name). There's a match for chars between second and third group to match the name format.