# Using regex cut full name to surname and initials

Tags: java, regex, text, split

I have a dataset of full names like:

```
Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich,
Petrov Petr Petrovich,
Ahmed Hasan,
Omar Singh,
Trump Donald John,
Mohmadi Hussein Ahmad Husseini
```

i need, using Java method

```
replaceAll(String regex, String text)
```

make a dataset like:

```
Ivanov I. I.,
Petrov P. P.,
Ahmed H.,
Omar S.,
Trump D. J.,
Mohmadi H. A. H.
```

I try to use - `replaceAll("(?:^[A-Za-z']*)|[^\\sА-ЯІЇЄ]", "."))` but it does not works.

What regex I need to use?

Comment: Have you tried with suggestions mentioned in this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248856/regex-full-name-to-abbreviated-name

Comment: Did you try simply splitting the string and using `charAt(0)` to extract just the first character?

Comment: What will you do when the name is `ten Brink Johann` or `von Heune Richard`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a single method call regex solution then use this regex using `\G`:

```
name = name.replaceAll("(\\p{L}+|\\G)(\\h+\\p{L})\\p{L}*", "$1$2.");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pILlYl/1)

`\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(\\p{L}+|\\G)`: Capture first name or end of previous match in group #1
- `(\\h+\\p{L})`: Capture white-space and start letter of next name component in group #2
- `\\p{L}*`:  Followed by 0 or more unicode letters